# R Language XML Parsing

Tags: xml, r

What is the best way to parse this [XML document](http://open.worldbank.org/countries) so that it is available in R?  I would like for each country node to be an independent R object.

Answer (score 3):

[R & SPlus XML Parsers](http://www.omegahat.org/RSXML/Overview.html) supplies XML parsers and [examples](http://www.omegahat.org/RSXML/Overview.html#TreeExamples).

2nd result for Googling `r programming xml`.